# How can open an image in a image viewer in php

Tags: php

How can open an image in a image viewer in php ?

Any code like `openwith()` ?

Comment: I have literally no idea what you are asking for.  27 question marks doesn't make a question.  Please provide more information.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 10.04, my need is using php how can i open an image ???

Comment: You need to look at imagemagick for PHP or the gd library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the image to the browser, but that's pretty much it. If you'd prefer people to save it/open it in an external app, you can use the `Content-disposition: attachment` header but what people actually do with it is up to them and their browser.